# Jmeter 2.13 vs Jmeter 3.0 Which is the better to run load Test?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

Currently, we are using the JMeter 2.13 version for load testing. I am planning to migrate to JMeter 3.0 version.

I have not started working on the JMeter 3.0 till now.I don't know pros and cons of it.

Please suggest me, Shall I upgrade scripts to 3.0 or shall I continue with Jmeter2.13.

Answer (score 2):

Of course it's better to go with newer version. Apart from new technologies are showing up each day and you need to be able to test them, there are always bug fixes and improvements, performance boost,...

For full list of fixes, improvements and new stuff, refer to change logs:

[History of Previous Changes](http://jmeter.apache.org/changes_history.html#New%20and%20Noteworthy)

By the way, if you are planning to move to newer version, why don't go to 3.2 directly?

[3.1 to 3.2 Change Log](http://jmeter.apache.org/changes.html)

Comment: Thank u, Ivan. I will go through 3.2 version

Answer (score 0):

The general recommendataion is use the latest version of JMeter where possible

- Pros: newer JMeter versions normally come with new features, performance improvements, bug fixes, etc.
- Cons:

  - there could be some [incompatible changes](http://jmeter.apache.org/changes.html#Incompatible%20changes) (normally you will need to override some [JMeter Properties](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) to revert JMeter configuration to match previous version behaviour, restore deprecated elements if you are using them in the tests, etc.
  - results on newer JMeter version might be not inline with what you used to have, i.e. due to aforementioned performance improvements JMeter could generate higher loads

Comment: Hi Dmitri,

My app server gets down during load test using latest 3.3 version of jmeter, however works fine in older jmeter 2.13

Any idea, I'm not figuring out since I'm using the the same script in both of the versions.

Only one thing I notice is; the Memory usage gets increased significantly while running using latest 3.3 version of Jmeter.